# how can i fix "add_lunch_combo is obsolete. Use COMMON_LUNCH_CHOICES in your AndroidProducts.mk instead."?

Tags: android, rom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNqM1.png)

I am trying to build custom rom first time ,in that filed i am newbie so i need help to complete that project , now i am stuck in device/realme/rmx1921/vendorsetup.sh and . build/envsetup.sh file i get error and warning and when i go for next step which is lunch then i can't get my combo lunch list

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the [Android documentation states](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/new-device#makefiles), `add_lunch_combo` can be found in the `device/<vendor>/<model>/vendorsetup.sh` file, but it is only used for Android 9 or lower.

Instead you need to use `COMMON_LUNCH_CHOICES` in the `device/<vendor>/<model>/AndroidProducts.mk` so the device can be chosen from the Lunch menu.

If your `vendorsetup.sh` is:

```
add_lunch_combo lineage_RMX1921-userdebug
add_lunch_combo lineage_RMX1921-user
add_lunch_combo lineage_RMX1921-env
```

Then you should modify your `AndroidProducts.mk` to add:

```
COMMON_LUNCH_CHOICES :=  \
    lineage_RMX1921-userdebug \
    lineage_RMX1921-user \
    lineage_RMX1921-env
```

Now you could remove the `add_lunch_combo` lines from `vendorsetup.sh` to get rid of the warnings or, as in your case, delete the file if it's not needed for anything else.